# Calculating every n-th row with a different format

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007

I'm trying to make a formula work on a time-table, **where every 7th row I have a sum of the work-time for a week and then I want them to sum them altogether from beginning of data to current week**.

Technically it is possible to just manually add them together, but I would like to have it automated and furthermore to learn how to use the function properly.

Screenshot for better visualization:

[image]

In the column "Nadcas" I have listed overtimes from Monday to Tuesday.
Under it is a SUM of those numbers. Right to it, the second highlighted field is the Overtime total. Logically, the first week is going the total of the overtimes to be the same as overtime of the first week.

In the table under it, it's the same deal. However, the overtimes on the right are calculated incorrectly. It should be 0:29 + 1:32 = 2:01.

**Biggest issue is, the sumtotal formula doesn't correctly calculate, when the field type is in hours, and some are text fields**

Any idea how to do it?

---

*OPTIONAL, can skip if you know the answer*:
 I have found a way to make the formula work, in the table here:

[image]

You can see the numbers are added up correctly. The formula I used (for the last sum cell, that equates to 11) is:

`=SUMPRODUCT(--(MOD(ROW(A12:A23) - ROW(A12) +1; 4)=0); A12:A23)`

Sum product does a matrix multiplication, mod returns 1 or 0 depending if X/4 gives .0 as rest and -- negates the result. Easily said, we have two matrices eg. {0; 0; 1} and {1; 2; 3} so the result is 0x1 + 0x2 + 1x3 = 3.

When we visualize that on our formula, it would look like:

[image]

[ For more info, I found this explanation pretty helpful, even though it's for columns. https://exceljet.net/formula/sum-every-nth-column ]

This should by all means work on the main table as well, but I guess because of formatting it doesn't.

Comment: Are you answering your own question in the question?

Comment: @Scott Craner Yes and no... The solution should be by all principles working, however as you can see it displays incorrect data and I don't know why. I've posted the optional part as a way to help people to solving the issue, but it's not the direct answer.

Comment: In your optional solution, why is the sum of rows 20-22 = 2?  Should it not be 3?

Comment: How did you get a negative time in G12, G18 and G19? Excel **doesn't do negative time**.

Comment: @Jeeped that was a rather nifty work-around. Excel Options -> Advanced -> Tick use 1904 Date System

Comment: @KarlKristjansson oops apologies, that was just me entering the SUM formula from row 21 instead of 20. But it has no bearing on the actual formula I was using. It calculated 3+6+2=11 so it works. It simply should have been 3+6+3=12

Answer (score 0):

If you are consistent with the format of the sheet, you can make use of the data in the second column "Den"- if we check this column for non blank cells and sum corresponding values in column G, we can have our answer.

Assuming following layout of the sheet, following formula should work:

[image]

```
'=SUM(IF(A$2:A6<>"",B$2:B6))
```

Executed with Ctrl+Shift+Enter

The fixed referencing in A$2:A6 makes sure that as you copy down the formula, the the entire range from to top to the cell-one-above the current is selected. Hope this helps!